# Regex for questions taking multiple sentences

Tags: python, python-re

I'm using re to take the questions from a text. I just want the sentence with the question, but it's taking multiple sentences before the question as well. My code looks like this:

```
match = re.findall("[A-Z].*\?", data2)
print(match)
```

an example of a result I get is:

```
 'He knows me, and I know him. Do YOU know me? Hey?'
```

the two questions should be separated and the non question sentence shouldn't be there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What counts as a sentence? are you looking for `([^\?\.]+\?)`?

Comment: Though not using regex, you may want to have a look at a natural language processing library like spacy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212589/how-to-check-if-a-sentence-is-a-question-with-spacy) for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` character in regex matches any text, including periods, which you don't want to include. Why not simply match anything besides the sentence ending punctuation?

```
questions = re.findall(r"\s*([^\.\?]+\?)", data2)
# \s*       sentence beginning space to ignore
# (         start capture group
# [^\.\?]+  negated capture group matching anything besides "." and "?" (one or more)
# \?        question mark to end sentence
# )         end capture group
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for letters, digits, and whitespace that end with a `'?'`.

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.findall('[\w\d\s]+\?', s)]
['Do YOU know me?', 'Hey?']
```

There would still be some edge cases to handle, like there could be punctuation like a `','` or other complexities.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `^` at the beginning of your expression so your regex expression should look like this: `"^[A-Z].*\?"`.

"Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. This matches a position, not a character."

If you have multiple sentences in your line you can use the following regex:

```
"(?<=.\s+)[A-Z].*\?"
```

`?<=` is called positive lookbehind. We try to find sentences which either start in a new line or have a period (.) and one or more whitespace characters before them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z][^?.]*\?(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[A-Z]` Match a single uppercase char A-Z
- `[^?.]*\?` Match 0+ times any char except `?` and `.` and then match a `?`
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LvxRYB/1)